# Asp.net Core Get User by User Id

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

Using Asp.net Core Identity and entity framework core, how can I get an asp.net user object by it's UserId property?  I know it's possible to get the current logged in user from the HttpContext.User object using:

```
UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User)
```

However when an admin is logged in, I want them to be able to access/modify any user's data in order to update user Emails and PhoneNumbers, which by default are part of the asp.net user object.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
var userRecord = _userManager.GetUserById(model.userId);
//update user record
userRecord.Email = model.Email;
userRecord.PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber;

var newRecord = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(userRecord);
```

but obvisously, the UserManager.GetUserById() method does not currently exist.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use `FindByIdAsync` for that:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.userId);
```

Answer (score 14):

You can get the current user one of this ways:

```
// Get the current user ID from the user claims (no DB hit)    
int currentUserId = int.Parse(User.FindFirst(Claims.UserId).Value);
```

And then retrieve the current user entity:

```
// Either via DB context:
var currentUser = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == currentUserId);

// or via Usermanager:
var sameUser = UserManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == currentUserId);
```

Or just this way:

```
var currentUser = UserManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
```

Comment: This has helped me to populate the current Identity User data in a view.


var currentUser = UserManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);

Comment: Don't use `DbContext` in connection with `UserManager`. An error like "there is already a tracked entity with this Id" can occur.

Comment: @Mike you can turn off change tracking in the scope (or even better, globally) to prevent that issue from happening, as long as you don't need change tracker

Comment: This is why I used `DbContext` in the first place - to update an entry :-)  But all entities fetched via `UserManager` shall be saved using `UserManager`.