# ViewComponent does not recognize AspNetCore.Identity "User"

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to create a ViewComponent for a series of checkboxes based on this article here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2

And this SO answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42853705/2300177

Seems like a perfect case scenario for what I'm trying to do. However, I've created my ViewComponent to include Identity `UserManager` to get the `userId`:

```
using BlogPlayground.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlogPlayground.ViewComponents
{
    public class LatestArticlesViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;


        public LatestArticlesViewComponent(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            string userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

            var lastArticles = await _context.Article
                                            .OrderByDescending(a => a.CreatedDate)
                                            .Take(howMany)
                                            .ToListAsync();
            return View(lastArticles);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call this line:

```
string userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
```

I'm getting an error for `User`that reads:

> cannot convert from 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal' to
>   'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal'

This exact code works in all my controllers and I have no idea where the `User` even comes from. Seems like magic, but I'm guessing somewhere inherent inside Identity? Or did I just miss something included in my controllers? (I searched "User" in my controllers and can't link that to anything.)

I'm using the Pomelo MySQL nuget package if that makes a difference? I wouldn't think so.

Anyone know what I'm missing and how to eliminate this error?

Update: Seems it will work with this (at least it gets rid of the error):

```
string userId = _userManager.GetUserId(Request.HttpContext.User);
```

Is that the same thing? Is there a using statement I'm missing? Visual studio (2017) usually clues me in to what I'm missing.

Comment: Kindly go through this link. It may be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30701006/how-to-get-the-current-logged-in-user-id-in-asp-net-core

Comment: casting the user to claims principal should solve the problem `(ClaimsPrincipal)User`

Comment: @ElyasEsna Hi Elyas, thanks for the reply. That seems to have made the error go away. Now I just need get back around to testing it... when I was reading more into that first link, seems ViewComponents are their own thing. So, I'm kind of leaning away from it.

Answer (score 1):

We add

`using System.Security.Claims;`

We can access the current user with the following code:

`var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync((ClaimsPrincipal)User);`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you configured `services.AddDefaultIdentity` and enabled `app.UseAuthentication` `Identity` in your `Startup`.

This is needed to make it available to the app through `dependency injection`, so you can get it loaded in your `LatestArticlesViewComponent`.

See the details here: [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I did all that. As I explained, it works ok in my controllers, just not in the ViewComponent.

Comment: @SumNone as for retrieving the current user ID check [Asp.net Core Get User by User Id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52503510/804385).

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'm aware of that way too. I'm actually doing that in my api where the user is not authed through Identity and doing quick verification of the email address. I guess I'm just looking for why the ControllerBase "User" doesn't seem to work. I'm kind of OCD about code uniformity. :)

Comment: If you pickup the user details from JWT token (with AddJwtBearer) - the trick thing here - override default Name claim with what you have in your token claims (you can decode it with jwt.io online). I mean your `options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters  {  NameClaimType = "yourclaimname" }`  By default `NameClaimType` a fully qualified URI - see https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/overriding-name-claimtype-aspnetcore-oidc/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `UserClaimsPrincipal` property of `ViewComponent` instead of the `User` property, so

`string userId = _userManager.GetUserId(UserClaimsPrincipal);`